# Unable to to use to my mongodb Atlas database

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am using MongoDB Atlas as my database.
when I search http://localhost:5000/book.
I got a error like this - MongoServerError: user is not allowed to do action [find] on [product.book].
did I search wrong? It should be book or books.

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
require('dotenv').config();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');

// midlewarwe

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASS}@cluster0.ibawcfn.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1,
});

async function run() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const bookCollection = client.db('product').collection('book');

    app.get('/book', async (req, res) => {
      const query = {};
      const cursor = bookCollection.find(query);
      const books = await cursor.toArray();
      res.send(books);
    });
    // app.post('/books', async (req, res) => {

    //     const  newBook = req.body;
    //     const result = await bookCollection.insertOne(newBook);
    //     res.send(result);
    // });
  } finally {
  }
}
run().catch(console.dir);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world ');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('listening on port ', port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is likely caused by database access to your MongoDB Atlas. Your `DB_USER` must have at least *Only read any database* role to perform read operation or *Read and write to any database* role to perform both read and write.

1. Go to your MongoDB Atlas console
2. On the left hand menu, select *Database Access*
3. Identify the *username* you use for your `DB_USER`
4. Find that username and select *EDIT* in *Actions* column
5. Find *Built-in Role* menu in *Database User Privileges* section
6. Expand the menu and choose either *Only read* or *Read and write* role
7. Finally, click *Update User* button to apply change.